# File Reading problems in Python

Tags: string, file-io, python-3.x

While Reading the files in python using
 `f = open ("filename.txt")`
and accessing the data with 
 `f.read(1)`
and finally finding the position of stream usibg
 `f.tell()`
for every step; We get a continous numbering starting from 0 to the current position.

The problem i am facing is that i am actually getting a random number as `f.tell()` for some positions and then continung the numbers.
For examle, the `f.tell()` outputs look something ike the following

```
0
1
2
3
133454568679978
6
7
8...
```

Any idea why this is happening?

My Code :

```
f=open("temp_mcompress.cpp")
current = ' '
   while current != '' :
   print(f.tell())
   current = f.read(1)

f.close()
```

Temp_mcompress.cpp file :

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int a)
{
}
```

OUtput :
`0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 18446744073709551636
 18446744073709551638
 23
 24
 25
 26
 27
 28
 29
 30
 31
 32
 33
 34
 35
 36
 37
 18446744073709551655
 40
 41
 43
 44`

Comment: Your code works for me.  I get 0 ... 41.  What are you trying to do?  You could get the same result using: import os
for pos in range(0, os.path.getsize("temp_mcompress.cpp") + 1):
    print pos

Comment: I am actually going for reading files and manupulations but I am constantly facing that error. I do not understand why i am getting a problem with the output so randomly.

Comment: related [Python file.tell() giving strange numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15934950/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I might have found the problem which may still be applicable to python 3.x:
source: http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html

> tell()
>
> Return the file's current position, like stdio's ftell().
>
> Note: On Windows, tell() can return illegal values (after an fgets())
>   when reading files with Unix-style line-endings. Use binary mode
>   ('rb') to circumvent this problem.