# Reading file stops at halfway

Tags: python, blender

I am writing a direct x importer for Blender, to be able to open ascii .x files. For this I try to make a good Python script. I am pretty new to it, actually I just started, but got good results, except a strange ... ummm ... problem: my .x file is pretty large, exactly 3 263 453 bytes long. I will not put my whole code here, just some workaround so the problem is still visible, and in console.

```
>>> teszt = open('d:\DRA_ACTORDEF_T0.x','rt')
>>> teszt
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='d:\\DRA_ACTORDEF_T0.x' mode='rt' encoding='cp1250'>
```

then I read the file:

```
>>> t2 = teszt.readlines()
>>> len(t2)
39768
```

but then again, when I verify:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.fstat(teszt.fileno()).st_size
3263453
```

Could someone lend me a hand and tell me, what the problem is? Maybe I am to set a buffer size or such? Got no idea, how this works in Python.

I open the file same way as above, and I use `.readline()`.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

The code simplified. I need `.readline()`.

```
fajlnev = 'd:\DRA_ACTORDEF_T0.x'

import bpy
import os

fajl = open(fajlnev, 'rt')
fajl_teljes_merete = os.fstat(fajl.fileno()).st_size

while (fajl.tell() < fajl_teljes_merete):
    print(fajl.tell(),fajl.readline())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines` returns a list of lines, so when you do `len(t2)` this will return the number of lines in the file and the length of a file.

If you want the numbers to match you should do:

```
with open('your_file', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
print(len(data))
```

Also if the file is encoded `rt` might incorrectly interpret the newlines. So it's much safer to do something like:

```
import io
with io.open('your_file', 'r', encoding='your_file_encoding') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

And if you want a streaming line by line read then it's best to do:

```
import io
with io.open('d:\\DRA_ACTORDEF_T0.x', 'r', encoding='your_encoding') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

This will take care of streaming and not reading the whole file into memory.

If you still want to use `readline`:

```
import io
filename = 'd:\\DRA_ACTORDEF_T0.x'
size = os.stat(filename).st_size
with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='your_encoding') as f:
    while f.tell() < size:
         # Do what you want
         line = f.readline()
```

Comment: With len(t2) you were right, I checked and it is good, and will use as workaround if nothing else better. I modified my question, could you please check it again? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to keep readline? I have to interpret the lines and the data in them. The stucture of my code is like "interpret and read new line only if needed" and not "read a line then interpret", so I would not use for if it can be avoided.

Comment: Somewhy it is not working, it clips a huge part of the file. I dropboxed a screenshot, describes best:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82074530/rf.png

Comment: Can you attach the file also so I can check and debug it?

Comment: I dropboxed the file and the current state of the importer:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82074530/Archive.7z
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35205/discussion-between-zeiksz-and-viktor-kerkez)

Comment: Found the bug: [Python file.tell() giving strange numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934950/python-file-tell-giving-strange-numbers) and also [issue16273](http://bugs.python.org/issue16273). Basically don't use tell with files opened in text mode, just in binary mode.