# Python file.tell gives wrong value location

Tags: python, seek, tell

I am trying to extract a number of locations from an existing file using Python. This is my current code for extracting the locations:

```
    self.fh = open( fileName , "r+")
    p = re.compile('regGen regPorSnip begin')
    for line in self.fh :
        if ( p.search(line) ):
            self.porSnipStartFPtr = self.fh.tell()
            sys.stdout.write("found regPorSnip")
```

This snippet is repeated a number of times (less the file open) with different search values, and seems to work: I get the correct messages, and the variables have values.

However, using the code below, the first write location is wrong, while subsequent write locations are correct:

```
    self.fh.seek(self.rstSnipStartFPtr,0)
    self.fh.write(str);
    sys.stdout.write("writing %s" % str )
    self.rstSnipStartFPtr = self.fh.tell()
```

I have read that passing certain `read`/`readline` options to `fh` can cause an erroneous tell value because of Python's tendency to 'read ahead'.  One suggestion I saw for avoiding this is to read the whole file and rewrite it, which isn't a very appealing solution in my application.

If i change the first code snippet to:

```
  for line in self.fh.read() :
        if ( p.search(line) ):
            self.porSnipStartFPtr = self.fh.tell()
            sys.stdout.write("found regPorSnip")
```

Then it appears that `self.fh.read()` is returning only characters and not an entire line. The search never matches. The same appears to hold true for `self.fh.readline()`.

My conclusion is that `fh.tell` only returns valid file locations when queried after a write operation.

Is there a way to extract the accurate file location when reading/searching?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15935038/8747

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cause is (rather obscurely) explained in the docs for a file object's `next()` method:

> When a file is used as an iterator, typically in a for loop (for example,
>   for line in f: print line), the next() method is called repeatedly.
>   This method returns the next input line, or raises StopIteration when
>   EOF is hit. In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping
>   over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the next() method
>   uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead
>   buffer, combining next() with other file methods (like readline()) does
>   not work right. However, using seek() to reposition the file to an
>   absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer.

The values returned by `tell()` reflect how far this hidden read-ahead buffer has gotten, which will typically be up to a few thousand bytes beyond the characters your program has actually retrieved.

There's no portable way around this.  If you need to mix `tell()` with reading lines, then use the file's `readline()` method instead.  The tradeoff is that, in return for getting usable `tell()` results, iterating over a large file with `readline()` is typically significantly slower than using `for line in file_object:`.

### Code

Concretely, change the loop to this:

```
line = self.fh.readline()
while line:
    if p.search(line):
        self.porSnipStartFPtr = self.fh.tell()
        sys.stdout.write("found regPorSnip")
    line = fh.readline()
```

I'm not sure that's what you really *want*, though:  `tell()` is capturing the position of the start of the *next* line.  If want the position of the *start* of the line, then you need to change the logic, like so:

```
pos = self.fh.tell()
line = self.fh.readline()
while line:
    if p.search(line):
        self.porSnipStartFPtr = pos
        sys.stdout.write("found regPorSnip")
    pos = self.fh.tell()
    line = fh.readline()
```

or do it with a "loop and a half":

```
while True:
    pos = self.fh.tell()
    line = self.fh.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if p.search(line):
        self.porSnipStartFPtr = pos
        sys.stdout.write("found regPorSnip")
```

Comment: The file isn't huge so the penalty of using readline i don't believe will be an issue. the first option is the one that is the most appropriate.  the start of the next line is OK.  it seems that testing for empty file while reading the line can't be done when a file pointer is required.  Thanks for the clarification.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fantastic explanation thanks a ton!  I also found this issue processing a large file but got around it by keeping an offset variable manually (offset += len(line)) instead of calling fh.tell().  This way you can keep the optimizations included with next()

Comment: @dugloon, that should work on Linuxy systems, but `tell()` results on text-mode files in Windows aren't generally simple byte offsets into the file.  Python inherits this limitation from C.  That's why the docs say "In text files (those opened without a b in the mode string), only seeks relative to the beginning of the file are allowed (the exception being seeking to the very file end with seek(0, 2)) and the only valid offset values are those returned from the f.tell(), or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour."

Comment: Thanks Tim!  I forgot to add that piece - I am opening with mode="rb"

Answer (score 0):

I guess I dont understand the issue

```
>>> fh = open('test.txt')
>>> fh.tell()
0L
>>> fh.read(1)
'"'
>>> fh.tell()
1L
>>> fh.read(5)
'a" \n"'
>>> fh.tell()
7L
```

Comment: The problem is actually due to using `for line in file_object:` - there's another layer of buffering then.

Comment: ahh got ya ... ok Ill delete this

Comment: why `for line in file_object` (the pythonic way) is a problem?