# More streamline way to count lines in file (python)

Tags: python, biopython

I wrote this to retrieve FASTA sequences of a list of protein accession numbers (acc_list.txt), each on a new line, and write them to a txt file (prot_list).

```
x=0
with open("acc_list.txt","r") as input:
    number = sum(1 for items in input) ###
with open("acc_list.txt","r") as input:
    with open ("prot_list.txt","w") as output:
        for acc in input:
            handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein",id=acc,rettype="fasta")
            x+=1
            print("Dealing with", str(acc.strip()), str(x), "out of", str(number), sep=" ")
            output.write(handle.read())
```

It is a big list so the penultimate line gives me an idea of the progress.

As you can see, `number = sum(1 for items in input)` gives the total number of lines, but I have to open and close the file separate, because if I put that under the latter `with` statement, i.e.

```
x=0
with open("acc_list.txt","r") as input:
    with open ("prot_list.txt","w") as output:
        for acc in input:
            number = sum(1 for items in input) ###
            handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein",id=acc,rettype="fasta")
            x+=1
            print("Dealing with", str(acc.strip()), str(x), "out of", str(number), sep=" ")
            output.write(handle.read())
```

it stops after counting items and gives no other outputs.
I'm guessing this is because `number = sum(1 for items in input)` iterates through the file and ends the iteration too.

I am curious as to whether there is a more efficient way to obtain the number of lines in a file? I can imagine that if I work with an even bigger list, there may be problems with my approach. I've seen older answers and they all involve iterating through the file first.

Comment: `1 + input.read().count('\n')` also works, though only timing will show if it is any faster.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it still needs to be put under its own `with` statement. I guess there is no way around it...

Comment: I assume you can't use with open("acc_list.txt","r") as input: inputz = input.readlines() and work on inputz  , because you don't want to load the entire list at once, right ?

Comment: @KcsA7466 if you find any of the answers helpful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting them

Answer (score 0):

copying from here [Is there a way to shallow copy an existing file-object ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367423/is-there-a-way-to-shallow-copy-an-existing-file-object)

I've ended up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun  7 11:40:04 2021

@author: Pietro


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67850117/more-streamline-way-to-count-lines-in-file-python

"""


from Bio import Entrez

from itertools import tee




x=0
    
with open("acc_list.txt", "r") as input:
    with open ("prot_list.txt","w") as output:  
        input1, input2 = tee(input, 2)
    
    
        number = sum(1 for items in input2)-1
        print(number)
    
    
        for acc in input1:
            if acc.strip() != '': 
                try:
                    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein",id=acc,rettype="fasta")
                    x+=1
                    print("Dealing with", str(acc.strip()), str(x), "out of", str(number), sep=" ")
                    output.write(handle.read())
                except:
                    pass
```

Not sure is faster or it is what you were looking for, let us know.

Besides that I noticed that at the end of my acc_list.txt file I always get end of file empty line as an empty accession  number so kind of t
found an elaborate way to suppress it

Comment: oops .... it was me that inserted the empty line !!! scrap that bit

Comment: Hi pippo, thank you for the suggestions. I've been very occupied and I'll take a look soon!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting yourself, you can let existing tools like `grep` do the job:

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run(['grep', '-c', '>', 'acc_list.txt'], check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
seq_count = int(p.stdout)
```

In my tests, this was faster than opening and counting in Python, especially for larger files. Counting `>` instead of line breaks also saves you from issues when the last line doesn't include a `\n`.

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you for the suggestion. I've been very occupied and I'll take a look soon!