# python: file i/o counting characters without new lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file named number.txt. It contains the following:

```
0
1
2
3
```

My code:

```
def main():
   inFile = open("number.txt", "r")
   text = inFile.read() 
   inFile.close()
   print(len(text))
main()
```

I have tried to use the above code to print out how many characters are in the file. It prints out 8, but there are only 4 characters.
I know that when python reads in the file it adds a newline after each line, and this could be extra characters. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: It is not `python` that adds a new line after each line.. _the_ file itself has a new line at every line by definition!

Answer (score 4):

The file contains a newline between each line. To filter it out, you can either recreate the string without those newlines with `replace`, `split`, or similar, or count the newlines and subtract them from the length (which is faster/more efficient).

```
with open("number.txt", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()
length_without_newlines = len(text) - text.count('\n')
```

Edit: As @lvc says, Python converts all line endings to '\n' (0x0A), including windows newlines ('\r\n' or [0x0D, 0x0A]), so one need only search for '\n' when finding new line characters.

Comment: You shouldn't override the built-in `len`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Whoa, good catch. That would have been a really annoying issue for OP to debug!

Comment: By default, `open` works with universal newline support (on text files) - ie, it handles the intricacies for you, and turns all newlines into just \n. If it didn't, this would be wrong for Windows-style \r\n newlines because it would count each one as *two* newlines instead of one.

Comment: @lvc Thanks, another good catch. Other languages I code in don't have that feature, so I frequently forget about it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

As Antonio said in the comment the newline characters are in the file.
if you want, you can remove them:

```
def main():
   inFile = open("number.txt", "r")
   text = inFile.read() 
   inFile.close()
   text = text.replace('\n', '')  # Replace new lines with nothing (empty string).
   print(len(text))
main()
```

Comment: Are the \n being replaced with spaces?

Comment: No. '' is an empty string, so they will just be removed.

Comment: You don't need to replace '\r'.  When opening the file in text mode (the default), new line characters will automatically be translated to just '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your script is correct: in fact new line are character too (they only are invisible!)

To omit the new line characters (referred in strings with `\n` or `\r\n`) then you have to substitute them with an empty string.

See this code:

```
def main():
   inFile = open("number.txt", "r")
   text = inFile.read()
   text = text.replace("\r\n","") #in windows, new lines are usually these two 
   text = text.replace("\n","")
```

caracters.
       inFile.close()
       print(len(text))
    main()

for more information about what `\r\n` and `\n` are, try: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: The second replace won't ever do anything, because all '\n's are already gone.  (And it's not necessary to care about this anyway -- see my other comment.)

Comment: As I said, the second replace can't possibly ever find anything.  You already deleted all `\n` characters, so for sure you won't find any `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.rstrip('\n')`. This will remove newlines from the right side of the string, and nothing else. Note that python should convert all newline chars to `\n`, regardless of platform. I would also recommend iterating over the lines of the file, rather than dumping it all to memory, in case you have a large file.

Example code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   count = 0
   with open("number.txt", "r") as fin):
       for line in fin:
           text = line.rstrip('\n')
           count += len(text)
   print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('number.txt', 'rb') as in_file:
        print abs(len(in_file.readlines()) - in_file.tell())
```

Comment: For text files, `in_file.tell()` gives you ["an opaque number"](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell). It isn't guaranteed to be the character length of the file.

Comment: I suppose 'rb' must fix tell behaviour, was metioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934950/python-file-tell-giving-strange-numbers

Comment: 'rb' puts it in binary mode, where `tell()` gives you the number of *bytes* read. That's fine for single-byte encodings, but potentially wrong for, eg, UTF8. AFAIK, it also forces universal newline support off, so Windows \r\n newlines will be counted as two bytes rather than one character. The only reliable way to count the number of *characters* in a file really is to read all of them in and take the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the print line, like this:

```
    print(len(text.replace("\n", "")))
```