# f.tell() returns an exorbitant number

Tags: python, io

While reading a text file line by line with `readline()` at some point `tell()` returns a number that is much, much larger that the total file size.

Here is my code:

```py
import io
with open(test_fpath, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    size = f.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)

    f.seek(0)
    while f.tell() < size:
        previous_position = f.tell()
        line = f.readline()

        if f.tell() > size:
            print('size: {}'.format(size))
            print('position: {}'.format(f.tell()))
            print('previous_position: {}'.format(previous_position))
            print('line read: {}'.format(repr(line)))
            break
```

Which yields:

```
size: 125348811
position: 18446744073804856772
previous_position: 95305153
line read: '\n'
```

What could be the reason for this strange behaviour?

I am on Windows 7, Python version is 3.6.6.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: Yes, I am. Should have put it in the question. It is there now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934950/python-file-tell-giving-strange-numbers

Comment: Thank you. Should I delete the question or mark as duplicate?