# Tell() method not reliable when dealing with text files in Python

Tags: python, text-files, tell

It seems that the .tell() method is not very reliable when dealing with text files in python. I am trying to use this method to stand in for an EOF condition as found in other programming languages.

For various reasons, I do not want to iterate over the text file with a FOR loop but use a WHILE loop instead.

Below is some code that replicates the problem. I have included code that will generate a test.txt text file in a random way:

```py
import re
from random import randint


def file_len_lines(f_name):
    with open(f_name) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1


def file_len_chars(f_name, with_nls):
    char_count = 0
    with open(f_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            char_count += len(line)
            if with_nls:
                char_count += 1
            else:
                pass
    return char_count


def trim(sut):
    return re.sub(' +', ' ', sut).strip()


# Create test file
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    word_list = ("Betty Eats Cakes And Uncle Sells Eggs "*20).split()
    word_list[3] = ""
    # for num in range(len(word_list)):
    #     if randint(1, 2) == 1:
    #         word_list[num] = ""
    for word in word_list:
        print(word, file=f)

file_to_read = 'test.txt'
# file_to_read = 'Fibonacci Tree 01.log'


with open(file_to_read, "r") as f:
    count = 0
    file_length = file_len_chars(file_to_read, True)
    file_length_lines = file_len_lines(file_to_read)
    print(f"Lines in file = {file_length_lines}, Characters in file = {file_length}")
    f.seek(0)
    while f.tell() < file_length:
        count += 1
        text_line = f.readline()
        print(f"Line = {count}, ", end="")
        print(f"Tell = {f.tell()}, ", end="")
        print(f"Length {len(text_line)} ", end="")
        if text_line in ['', '\n']:
            print(count)
        elif trim(text_line).upper()[0] in "A E I O U".split():
            print(text_line, end='')
        else:
            print(count)
```

This code should always output something like:

```
Lines in file = 140, Characters in file = 897
Line = 1, Tell = 7, Length 6 1
Line = 2, Tell = 13, Length 5 Eats
Line = 3, Tell = 20, Length 6 3
...
Line = 138, Tell = 884, Length 6 Uncle
Line = 139, Tell = 891, Length 6 139
Line = 140, Tell = 897, Length 5 Eggs

Process finished with exit code 0
```

but instead, it mostly outputs something more like:

```
Lines in file = 140, Characters in file = 605
Line = 1, Tell = 7, Length 6 1
Line = 2, Tell = 18446744073709551630, Length 5 Eats

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You can see that on the last line of the output above, the .tell() method output went haywire and does not cycle through all 140 lines.

I am looking for a way to make the .tell() method behave or otherwise detect an EOF condition in another way to make break a WHILE loop.

Again, most advice found online says "iterate with a FOR loop". I do not want to do this for various reasons that are tedious to explain. *(Briefly, it will make the nature of my original code very unwieldy due to the nested flow diagram I intend to follow.)*

Comment: As the docs state the number returned by `TextIOBase.tell()` is opaque and "does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary storage". Possible solution is to use a binary file and convert each line afterwards (be aware of the line ending).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python file.tell() giving strange numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934950/python-file-tell-giving-strange-numbers)

Comment: This is a known limitation.  I don't know what you want to do, but the tell() function almost certainly isn't going to work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Cornelius, I realise this and asked anyway. Was hoping that somebody out there had since figured out a workaround to check for an EOF condition. Used a for loop in the meantime but it makes for some cumbersome repetitive code.

Comment: There are various ways to detect an EOF condition.  Read streams do it automatically, and their various read functions return an empty string if the file is at EOF.  As I said I don't know what you are trying to do, but reading/writing files is one of the most common operations and the Python standard library is designed to make it easy, without having to resort to the kind of low-level messing around you are doing here.