# Impossibly large offsets from `TextIOBase.tell()` at newlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I have a text file which contains newlines. Opened in text mode at the position of any newline, `.tell()` returns a very large number. Otherwise `.tell()` behaves normally. The offset at newlines is "impossibly large" because, although it's an "opaque number", `seek()`ing to that position fails with `OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer`.

Reading in binary mode behaves totally normally, and this happens only with certain files. Also, seeking to an "implied" offset (e.g. line 29 or 30, see output below) behaves normally. Any insight into what's going on?

Code:

```
# File content omitted due to NDA
with open(FILE, 'r') as fh:
    print(f"ENCODING: {fh.encoding}")
    while char := fh.read(1):
        print(fh.tell(), ':', char=='\n')
print('EOF')
```

Output:

```
ENCODING: UTF-8
1 : False
2 : False
3 : False
...
27 : False
28 : False
18446744073709551646 : True
340282367000166625996085689099021713438 : True
31 : False
32 : False
...
118 : False
119 : False
340282367000166625996085689099021713528 : True
121 : False
122 : False
...
180 : False
181 : False
340282367000166625996085689099021713590 : True
183 : False
184 : False
...
2012 : False
2013 : False
18446744073709553631 : False
1461501637671185285124623296198104371161410308063 : True
EOF
```

Python version:

```
3.8.6 (default, Nov 18 2020, 21:37:10) 
[GCC 10.2.0]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python file.tell() giving strange numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934950/python-file-tell-giving-strange-numbers)

Comment: @zvone Good catch - It's similar behavior, but, this is on Linux and the newline character is just `\r`. Explicitly setting `newline='\r' fixes it so apparently related to universal newlines